# How to replicate the ID search feature in Discord?

Tags: javascript, discord

In Discord if you want want to send a friend request to a user, you can enter it in the input bar below. Now the username can be long and there can be multiple usernames. The main detemining factor is the number followed after the username and a '#'.

As you can see below,

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, I am trying to make a input field where the user has to add some commands such as `username add/remove book/note title by author/title <body (if it's a note)>`. Using this short hand command a user in my app can add a new note, or a book to the database just by submiting this message on the website.
For instance I need to add a book, the username has to followed by an 'add' command, and then the 'title' after which the 'author' needs to be followed after the 'by'. Just like in the example above the 4 UNIQUE NUMBERs only follow after the '#' has been typed I want to be able to have 'username, add, remove, by' to act like the hashtag.
Do link me up to some documents, I do not expect an entire code written for me, I just need a starting point to begin my search since I cannot understand it.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: i haven't done anything accept just have a backend to parse it as a string later but nothing live for the user like in discord: since i dont know how to firstly make them act as 'keywords', and secondly how to differentiate text as the user is typing. Lastly, every keyword needs to be in an order, so if the user starts typing something else i need it to give an error* which i cannot since for that i'll need to track it live.

*eg. as the username is being typed it will be highlighted however if the add/remove does not follow the user will be prompted then title will follow until by is typed.

Comment: @Syntle do you have anything in mind?

Comment: tbh I don't completely understand what you're trying to achieve here, the last part of your question doesn't clarify your goal.

Comment: @Syntle lmao alright, i'll try reformatting that